# Set "style" in code in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, coding-style, page-break

I have a page with multiple tables on it and I want to have a page break for printing between these tables.  If I manually set the element's style to "page-break-after:always" it seems to work.

```
<table style="page-break-after:always;">
```

But I'm added the tables dynamically so I need to do it in code ... just don't know how.

(I have very little asp\html experience so this could be a very newbie question)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a page break after **every** table, then do not define your styling inline (with the style *attribute*) but in the head of your page or master page:

```
<head>
    <style>
        table {
            page-break-after: always;
        }
    </style>
<head>
```

Or define it in an external css file:

site.css:

```
table {
    page-break-after: always;
}
```

your html page:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site.css" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are adding the tables dynamically in JavaScript you can do:

using jQuery:

```
$('#myTable').css({'page-break-after':'always'});
```

using DOM methods:

```
myTableElem.setAttribute('style','page-break-after:always;');
//note, this fails in IE6/IE7/IE8(if not in standards mode) (due to an IE bug)

myTableElem.style.setAttribute('cssText', 'page-break-after:always;');//IE only way
```

It's likely obvious, but I would recommend using jQuery or a similar library that abstracts away bugs like these so you don't suffer from issues in some/all versions of IE.

Alternatively you can add a css class dynamically...

```
.page_break_after{
  page-break-after:always;
}
```

then just add the class to whatever you want to add it to:

```
$('#myTable').addClass('page_break_after');
```

or natively...

```
myTableElem.setAttribute('className', 'page_break_after');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new item to the Style collection of the dynamically created control:

```
HtmlTable dynamicTable;
...
dynamicTable.Style.Add("page-break-after","always");
```